# Network packets dropping for a few seconds every 3 minutes

Tags: network, ping

I've been having this problem for a few months now, and have not been able to figure out what the problem is.  I've noticed that when I'm on a video conference call, every few minutes, the video and audio will freeze for about 2-3 seconds.  To test my network connection, I decided to set up a ping to google (and my router), and noticed that whenever the network interruption would occur, my pings would timeout.  I've tested doing concurrent pings with 2 machines side by side, and can see that the other machine pings just fine during the period mine is acting up.  Here's an example of what I see when I'm pinging:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=76 ttl=64 time=1.192 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=77 ttl=64 time=2.622 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=78 ttl=64 time=2.103 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 79
Request timeout for icmp_seq 80
Request timeout for icmp_seq 81
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=81 ttl=64 time=1839.023 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=82 ttl=64 time=834.402 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=83 ttl=64 time=2.624 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=84 ttl=64 time=1.049 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=258 ttl=64 time=1.234 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=259 ttl=64 time=2.227 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 261
Request timeout for icmp_seq 262
Request timeout for icmp_seq 263
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=263 ttl=64 time=1101.699 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=264 ttl=64 time=98.018 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=265 ttl=64 time=1.613 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=266 ttl=64 time=3.222 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=437 ttl=64 time=1.814 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=438 ttl=64 time=0.970 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 440
Request timeout for icmp_seq 441
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=441 ttl=64 time=1878.315 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=442 ttl=64 time=874.096 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=443 ttl=64 time=3.527 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=616 ttl=64 time=1.466 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=617 ttl=64 time=1.430 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 619
Request timeout for icmp_seq 620
Request timeout for icmp_seq 621
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=620 ttl=64 time=2254.657 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=621 ttl=64 time=1250.068 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=622 ttl=64 time=254.426 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=623 ttl=64 time=1.744 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=796 ttl=64 time=2.274 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=797 ttl=64 time=0.937 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 800
Request timeout for icmp_seq 801
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=801 ttl=64 time=1111.394 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=802 ttl=64 time=106.473 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=803 ttl=64 time=0.953 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=804 ttl=64 time=1.191 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=975 ttl=64 time=0.897 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=976 ttl=64 time=1.557 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 978
Request timeout for icmp_seq 979
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=979 ttl=64 time=1801.378 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=980 ttl=64 time=797.444 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=981 ttl=64 time=1.651 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=982 ttl=64 time=4.567 ms
```

The problem seems to get temporary better after a restart, but eventually comes back.  I've tried closing most everything on my computer, but the problem persists.  I'm at a loss as to what could be wrong, and I'm hoping this community can offer some assistance and troubleshooting steps.

EDIT: I've added sections from a longer trace.  There's 1 ping every second, and breaking down the time between failures, we get the following intervals:

```
1-2: 182 seconds
2-3: 179 seconds
3-4: 179 seconds
4-5: 181 seconds
5-6: 178 seconds
```

From this, you can see I'm averaging a failure every 3 minutes (almost to the second).  I have no idea what would be running every 3 minutes that would cause this issue.

EDIT2: Here are my system specs:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,3
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  3.1 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 198.0.0.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 2.45f0
```

EDIT3: I tried hooking up my computer to the ethernet port, and the problem seemed to go away, but came back when I switched to wireless.  The other devices I tested on were also wireless, so I still feel that it's something to do with my computer, but specifically something with the wireless signal.

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening for any number of reasons, check that your drivers are all up to date. It could also be a hardware issue possibility with your router or a cable going bad. Or it could be on your internet service providers end, they may be cutting off your data for some reason or just have a bad connection to you.

Comment: I've done the work to verify that it's not an issue with my router or anything on the ISP by doing the same ping tests with other machines on the same network.  I've also seen this problem on my computer on other networks, and also have seen it on WiFi as well as Ethernet.  I've also gone through several osx updates, so I can't imagine it being a driver issue.

Comment: What year/model is your computer?

Comment: It could be your PCI card is going bad, check the model for that too.

Comment: Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,3
  Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 3.1 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
  Memory: 16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 198.0.0.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 2.45f0

Comment: This [article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1068601) has a couple solutions that may fix your problem. I'd try resetting your PRAM first and go down the comments in the article and see if that fixes your issue. Your mac uses the airport cards and could have some issue with that making something conflict with your network.